# Battleship Game C++, Placing user inputted boats

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure out how to place user inputted boats in a battleship game. The x and y integers are the location on the 10x10 board. and the orientation is 0 for horizontal and 1 for vertical. The boat_length is obviously the length of the boat (from 2 to 5). I want to return false if the boat cannot be placed on the 10x10 board and if there's another ship there, I cannot place it there either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
bool userboat(char boatArray[][BOARD_SIZE],int x, int y, int orientation, int boat_length){
    for(int yy = 0; yy < BOARD_SIZE; yy++){
        for(int xx = 0; xx < BOARD_SIZE; xx++){
            if(yy == y && xx == x){
                boatArray[yy][xx] = 'B';
                if(orientation == 0){
                    if(x+boat_length< BOARD_SIZE){
                        for(int boat = 0; boat<boat_length; boat++){
                            boatArray[yy][boat] =BOAT;
                        }
                    }else{
                        return false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if(yy+boat_length< BOARD_SIZE){
                    for(int boat = 1; boat<boat_length; boat++){
                        boatArray[boat][yy] =BOAT;
                    }
                }else{
                    return false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: So what is your actual question?  What part is not working or do you not know how to check these conditions?

Comment: The whole code is not working correctly, it is not returning the right values. This is my attempt at the solution but I cannot think of anything else

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You don't need to search through the entire board for the coordinates that were given to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about homework and is not useful for anyone else, than the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your following code:

```
boatArray[yy][boat] = BOAT;
```

To:

```
boatArray[yy][xx + boat] = BOAT;
```

Let's look over a simple example. If we want to place the boat at the position (2,2), we loop the entire 2D array until we reach xx == 2 && yy == 2 right?
Good. Now we check if this position (boatArray[yy][xx]) is empty (you should implement this). If it is empty we do the math and see if the boat can be placed inside the array. 
Now your loop looks like this:

```
for(int boat = 0; boat<boat_length; boat++)
          boatArray[yy][boat] = BOAT;
```

Which means that boatArray[yy][0], boatArray[yy][1], .. will get the value of BOAT. But you don't want that. Those are the first columns every time. What you should do instead is this (as I mentioned earlier):

```
boatArray[yy][xx + boat] = BOAT;
```

**EDIT:** Same thing for the other loop.